# Using System.Web in Xamarin android (xamarin.android.dll)

Tags: c#, android, http, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am pretty new to android development and using Xamarin for now.

All looks nice, however as soon I try to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` or `HttpWebRequest` I need the `System.Web`.

If I add the `System.Web` to the references its not being accepted.

Some research gives me the idea that `xamarin.android.dll` should have the `System.Web.dll` however I have no idea where to find this one.

Does anybody know how to solve this so `HttpUtility` and `HttpWebRequest` will be available in my android project?

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 12):

`HttpWebRequest` is part of the `System.Net` assembly while `HttpUtility` is part of the `System.Web.Services` assembly.

(Xamarin Studio).

To add those to your project, simply right click the `References` folder and choose `Edit references`

[image: Edit references]

In the Edit references dialog you simply make sure the checkbox is checked for `System.Net` and `System.Web.Services`.

[image]

(Visual Studio)

Right click the `References` folder and choose `Add reference`. Next scroll down the list in the `Assemblies -> Framework` tab and make sure the checkbox is checked for `System.Net` and `System.Web.Services`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes this is the one I am looking for however I see you are working with the Xamarin Studio and I work with VS 2012, any change I can get this library into VS2012?

Comment: This should work the same way in Visual Studio as in Xamarin Studio. See my updated answer

Comment: Correct but I dont have the once from the Android if I use the System.Web (which is from the C# framework) its giving errors

Comment: If you go nuts while searching for that package (like me), check if you also target WindowsPhone. For some reason I can't use it there, but on projects, targeting Android or iOS.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpWebRequest` is included in the `System.Net` namespace (`System` dll), and `HttpUtility` is in the `System.Web` namespace (requires `System.Web.Services` dll).

For a reference of which namespaces are available, and which dll they live in, see [Assemblies](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/assemblies/).

Comment: Not exact where I was looking for as the System.Web should be in the Xamarin.android but I have a hard time to find this one dll

Answer (score 0):

`Uri.EscapeDataString` or `Uri.UnescapeDataString` may also be an option.